# Bash - evaluate ENV Variable being stored in a command

Tags: python, bash

I want to save a command in a variable like this:

```
[user@smat-jupyterhub-nb-user ~]$ TESTCMD='python script.py'
[user@smat-jupyterhub-nb-user ~]$ SCRIPT=script.py
```

Running `$TESTCMD` works fine. But I also want to pass a variable to that command:

```
[user@smat-jupyterhub-nb-user ~]$ TESTCMD2='python $SCRIPT'
```

When I run this, I get an error. The Variable does not get evaluated.

```
[user@smat-jupyterhub-nb-user ~]$ $TESTCMD2
python: can't open file '/jup/projects/$SCRIPT': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How can I make this variable being evaluated after being stored in a variable itself?

Comment: You could use shebang and assign `TESTCMD2=$SCRIPT`

Comment: Don't use variable, just use a function for this

Comment: @anubhava: Does not work in this case, I don´t have to write this myself. I let some users pass a command to a programm which should be evaluated 1:1

Comment: Running user passed command strings *as is* would be inherently unsafe

Comment: I just tried to use `eval`. Seems to solve my problem. Anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: @anubhava: I know, it just does not matter in my case. Every user has its own container and can only destroy whatever they are using themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you used `'` quotes, instead of `"` preventing variable substitution.

```bash
$ FOO=echo
$ BAR=bar
$ XXX='${FOO} ${BAR}'
$ $XXX
${FOO}: command not found

$ XXX="${FOO} ${BAR}"
$ $XXX
bar
```

In fact the last one should be rather

```bash
$ XXX=""${FOO}" "${BAR}""
```

with variables additionally quoted in case any of their value contains space.

Comment: thank you! As Python User this behaviour was quite unexpected!

Comment: The variables are not additionally quoted in `XXX=""${FOO}" "${BAR}""`, which is equivalent to `XXX=${FOO}" "${BAR}` (this is ok but actually unquotes the variables). `XXX="${FOO} ${BAR}"` is just fine. Additional quotes make no sense anyway.

Comment: Also, storing a command with its arguments in a variable is an anti-pattern in `bash`. See [BashFAQ/050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: I'd impression shellcheck complains w/o that.